# CustomListView inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Need to display the custom listview on the fragment but it throws null pointer exception everytime.

Please assist me where i am going wrong.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = layoutinflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row, null);
            holder.Name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_download_label);
            holder.Download = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.Name.setText(mNames[position]);
        holder.Download.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView Name;
        Button Download;
    }
```

and the  on createview method is as follows

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gurbani_list, container, false);
           mLvList=(ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.lv_list);
           mTvDownload=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_download_label);
           switch (Utility.gurbaniItemSelected) {
           case 1:
            names=Utility.getInstance().getJaapJiSahib();
            break;
        }      

          mAdapter=new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), names);
          mLvList.setAdapter(mAdapter);  
        return mView;
    }
```

custom_list_row.xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_custom_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @downvoter give reason for downvote

Comment: Post your logcat and relevant code

Comment: Provide custom_list_row.xml code

Comment: Where is the null pointer exception originating from ?

Comment: @atok   at  this line holder.Name.setText(mNames[position]); it show null pointer

Comment: Is your `v_download_label textview` belong to `custom_list_row.xml` layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> at this line holder.Name.setText(mNames[position]);

If you say that is where you get `NullPointerException` then `Name` is null. Check if `custom_list_row.xml` has a textview with id `tv_download_label`. I don't think you have the textview in the layout that you inflate. Hence initialization fails.

In `custom_list_row.xml` you have only one textview with id `tv_custom_list`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_custom_list" // id is tv_custom_list
```

SO change this

```
holder.Name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_download_label);
```

to

```
holder.Name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_list);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Raghu but i have debugged it and the name has the values initialised

Comment: thank u so much you are right what a silly mistake i have done.Thanks for correcting me

Comment: @jyomin only objects can be null and if you say  `holder.Name.setText(mNames[position]);` causes NPE it means Name is null

Comment: ok thanks for sharing this knowledge i will take care of this in future

Answer (score 2):

You should replace this

```
 holder.Name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_download_label);
```

With

```
 holder.Name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_custom_list);
```

It's becoz there is no `TextView` with Id `tv_download_label` in your inflated layout.